# Trying to group an array of objects under same keys resulting in a new array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, javascript-objects

I have an array of `messages` consisting of objects, where each object represents a single message and the `created_at` key representing the date of the message. I am receiving this data from the API. Here is the structure that I get:

```
let messages = [
  {text: "A", status: 'r', created_at: "2020-02-06"},
  {text: "B", status: 's', created_at: "2020-02-06"},
  {text: "C", status: 'r', created_at: "2020-02-06"},
  {text: "D", status: 's', created_at: "2020-02-07"},
  {text: "E", status: 's', created_at: "2020-02-07"},
  {text: "F", status: 'r', created_at: "2020-02-09"},
  {text: "G", status: 's', created_at: "2020-02-09"},
  {text: "H", status: 's', created_at: "2020-02-10"}
]
```

I am using `vuejs` to render these messages in a chat application (similar to WhatsApp), where I want to display the date on top and the messages under that date in chronological order, just like WhatsApp. I am receiving the messages from the API in chronological order like the `messages` array I pasted above.
I would like to have the following output, so that I can use `v-for directive` in `vuejs` to loop through the `messages` and render them according to the date they were created:

```
  output:
    [
      {
        dt: "2020-02-06",
        arr: [
            {text: "A", status: 'r', created_at: "2020-02-06"},
            {text: "B", status: 's', created_at: "2020-02-06"},
            {text: "C", status: 'r', created_at: "2020-02-06"},
        ]
      },
      {
        dt: "2020-02-07",
        arr: [
            {text: "D", status: 's', created_at: "2020-02-06"},
            {text: "E", status: 's', created_at: "2020-02-06"},
        ]
      },
      {
        dt: "2020-02-09",
        arr: [
            {text: "F", status: 'r', created_at: "2020-02-09"},
            {text: "G", status: 's', created_at: "2020-02-09"},
        ]
      },
        {
        dt: "2020-02-10",
        arr: [
           {text: "H", status: 's', created_at: "2020-02-10"}
        ]
      },
    ]
```

Is there a library in lodash that can achieve this directly?

What I have tried so far:

I was able to group the dates in an array without the dates repeating, like so:

```
let dates = messages.map((item => {
    return item.created_at
}))
let uniq = [...new Set(dates)];
console.log(uniq)
```

...which gives the following output:

```
uniq = ["2020-02-06", "2020-02-07", "2020-02-09", "2020-02-10"]
```

I am not able to move ahead of this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution without using any external library:

```js
const messages = [
  {text: "A", status: 'r', created_at: "2020-02-06"},
  {text: "B", status: 's', created_at: "2020-02-06"},
  {text: "C", status: 'r', created_at: "2020-02-06"},
  {text: "D", status: 's', created_at: "2020-02-07"},
  {text: "E", status: 's', created_at: "2020-02-07"},
  {text: "F", status: 'r', created_at: "2020-02-09"},
  {text: "G", status: 's', created_at: "2020-02-09"},
  {text: "H", status: 's', created_at: "2020-02-10"}
]

let dupDates = messages.map((item => {
 return item.created_at
}))
let uniq = [...new Set(dupDates)];
let grouping = uniq.map(uniqItem => {
 let ret = messages.filter(msg => {
   return msg.created_at === uniqItem
  })
  return {
    dt: uniqItem,
         arr: ret
  }
})
console.log(grouping)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use lodash to group by the `created_at`, and then map to the required format:

```js
const messages = [
  {text: "A", status: 'r', created_at: "2020-02-06"},
  {text: "B", status: 's', created_at: "2020-02-06"},
  {text: "C", status: 'r', created_at: "2020-02-06"},
  {text: "D", status: 's', created_at: "2020-02-07"},
  {text: "E", status: 's', created_at: "2020-02-07"},
  {text: "F", status: 'r', created_at: "2020-02-09"},
  {text: "G", status: 's', created_at: "2020-02-09"},
  {text: "H", status: 's', created_at: "2020-02-10"}
]

const result = _.map(
  _.groupBy(messages, 'created_at'),
  (arr, dt) => ({ dt, arr })
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to require a big library if you don't have to - iterate over the array and organize it into an object, where the keys are the dates and values are arrays for each date. Then map the object's entries to turn it into an array of objects:

```js
let messages = [
  {text: "A", status: 'r', created_at: "2020-02-06"},
  {text: "B", status: 's', created_at: "2020-02-06"},
  {text: "C", status: 'r', created_at: "2020-02-06"},
  {text: "D", status: 's', created_at: "2020-02-07"},
  {text: "E", status: 's', created_at: "2020-02-07"},
  {text: "F", status: 'r', created_at: "2020-02-09"},
  {text: "G", status: 's', created_at: "2020-02-09"},
  {text: "H", status: 's', created_at: "2020-02-10"}
];
const messagesByDate = {};
for (const message of messages) {
  if (!messagesByDate[message.created_at]) {
    messagesByDate[message.created_at] = [];
  }
  messagesByDate[message.created_at].push(message);
}
const output = Object.entries(messagesByDate).map(([dt, arr]) => ({ dt, arr }));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `reduce` to build object and getting `Object.values` will simplify.

```js
const update = data => {
  return Object.values(
    data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      const dt = curr.created_at;
      acc[dt] =
        dt in acc
          ? { dt, arr: [...acc[dt].arr, { ...curr }] }
          : { dt, arr: [{ ...curr }] };
      return acc;
    }, {})
  );
};

let messages = [
  { text: "A", status: "r", created_at: "2020-02-06" },
  { text: "B", status: "s", created_at: "2020-02-06" },
  { text: "C", status: "r", created_at: "2020-02-06" },
  { text: "D", status: "s", created_at: "2020-02-07" },
  { text: "E", status: "s", created_at: "2020-02-07" },
  { text: "F", status: "r", created_at: "2020-02-09" },
  { text: "G", status: "s", created_at: "2020-02-09" },
  { text: "H", status: "s", created_at: "2020-02-10" }
];

console.log(update(messages));
```

Comment: this is a really good solution with minimum lines of code. Thanks!!